# Can someone help me understand this for loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop

I am trying to recycle this code from another source but I am having trouble understand the `for` loop in the second line. Can someone please clarify what exactly this line `title = [x for x in title if x not in stopWords]` is doing? `stopWords` is a list of words.

```
def title_score(title, sentence):

    title = [x for x in title if x not in stopWords]
    count = 0.0
    for word in sentence:
        if (word not in stopWords and word in title):
            count += 1.0

    if len(title) == 0:
        return 0.0

    return count/len(title)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[x for x in title if x not in stopWords]
```

It's a list comprehension. It means construct a list of all items in `title` (that's the `x for x in title` bit) that are not also in `stopWords` (per the `if x not in stopWords` bit).

---

You can see a similar effect with the following snippets. The first creates a list of all number in the inclusive range `0..9`:

```
>>> [x for x in range(10)]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

The second adds an `if` clause to only include odd numbers:

```
>>> [x for x in range(10) if x % 2 != 0]
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

---

And here's perhaps a better example, more closely aligned to your code:

```
>>> stopWords = "and all but if of the".split() ; stopWords
['and', 'all', 'but', 'if', 'of', 'the']

>>> title = "the sum of all fears".split() ; title
['the', 'sum', 'of', 'all', 'fears']

>>> [x for x in title]
['the', 'sum', 'of', 'all', 'fears']

>>> [x for x in title if x not in stopWords]
['sum', 'fears']
```

There you can see the "noise" words being removed in the final step.

Answer (score 0):

well, they say that python is like runnable pseudocode and I guess that applies here. it is creating a list and putting into it every item inside title where that item is not inside stopWords

Answer (score 0):

That is a list comprehension, equivalent to this loop:

```
newtitle = []
for x in title:
    if x not in stopwords;
        newtitle.append(x)
title = newtitle
```

In other words, it effectively *removes* any words from `title` if they also appear in `stopwords`.